# Probability of product of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a joint distribution function $F$ of two variables: 
And i have 2 pairs of independent Random variables:
$(X_1,X_2)$ is independent of $(X_1',X_2')$ both having distribution $F$.

I need to calculate the following probability in terms of $F$ the actual function is not given :

$Pr[(X_1 - X_1')(X_2 - X_2') > 0]$

I tried splitting it into

$Pr[(X_1 - X_1') > 0, (X_2 - X_2') > 0] + Pr[(X_1 - X_1') < 0, (X_2 - X_2') < 0]$

But i do not know how to proceed further.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to know more about $F(X_1,X_2)$.

- Suppose $X_1$ and $X_1^\prime$ are independently $N(0,1)$ and $X_2=X_1$ while $X_2^\prime = X_1^\prime$.  Then $\Pr[(X_1 - X_1')(X_2 - X_2') > 0] = 1$.
- Suppose $X_1$ and $X_1^\prime$ are independently $N(0,1)$ while  $X_2=-X_1$ and $X_2^\prime = -X_1^\prime$.  Then $\Pr[(X_1 - X_1')(X_2 - X_2') > 0] = 0$.

You can also get any intermediate probability, even before considering discrete distributions where $\Pr[(X_1 - X_1')(X_2 - X_2') = 0] \gt 0$.

In the comments, you asked if there was an integral. Assuming that the joint distribution has a joint density $f(x_1,x_2)$ [among other things, this would imply that the product being $0$ has probability zero] then you could write the probability as

$$\int_{x_1=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x_2=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x_1^\prime=-\infty}^{x_1} \int_{x_2^\prime=-\infty}^{x_2} f(x_1,x_2) f(x_1^\prime,x_2^\prime)\, dx_2^\prime \, dx_1^\prime  \, dx_2\, dx_1 + $$

$$\int_{x_1=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x_2=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x_1^\prime=x_1}^{\infty} \int_{x_2^\prime=x_2}^{\infty} f(x_1,x_2) f(x_1^\prime,x_2^\prime)\, dx_2^\prime \, dx_1^\prime  \, dx_2\, dx_1 .$$

You could simplify this slightly since $\displaystyle \int_{x_1^\prime=-\infty}^{x_1} \int_{x_2^\prime=-\infty}^{x_2} f(x_1^\prime,x_2^\prime)\, dx_2^\prime \, dx_1^\prime = F(x_1,x_2)$ and $\displaystyle \int_{x_1^\prime=x_1}^{\infty} \int_{x_2^\prime=x_2}^{\infty}  f(x_1^\prime,x_2^\prime)\, dx_2^\prime \, dx_1^\prime = 1-F(\infty,x_2)-F(x_1,\infty)+F(x_1,x_2)$ making the probability of $\Pr[(X_1 - X_1')(X_2 - X_2') = 0]$ equal to

$$\int_{x_1=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x_2=-\infty}^{\infty}  f(x_1,x_2) (1 -F(\infty,x_2) -F(x_1,\infty) +2F(x_1,x_2))  \, dx_2\, dx_1.$$

Comment: i don't need the value i just need to know how to calculate it like an integral formula or something.

Comment: @VikashB: I have given a couple of integrals